# How to process data after a counter reached to zero for a specific period of time, then the counter will start again after that peiod of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, counter, period

My scenario is that a node chooses a random number as a counter, then starts to auto-decrement the counter (I did this step). When the counter reaches to zero, then the node processes data for 1 minute only. After 1 minute of processing, the node will choose again a random number and auto-decrement it, then process the data for 1 minute. The node must do that repeatedly.

I have tried this:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://localhost';
var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL);

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("MQTT connected  "+ client.connected);
    client.subscribe('DAG1');
})

var MIN_PER_RANK =3;
var MAX_PER_RANK =5;

function animateValue(start, end) {
    if (start === end) return;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
            console.log (current);
        if (current === 0){
            console.log("finish counter")
            console.log("process data for 1 minute")

            client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
                processdata(topic, message)
            })   
        }

    }, 1000);
}

var randomvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_PER_RANK - MIN_PER_RANK  + 1) + MIN_PER_RANK);
animateValue(randomvalue, 0);

var start = true;
setInterval(function(){
    if(start){
        start = false;
    } else {
        start = true;
        console.log("start counter")
            
        var randomvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_PER_RANK - MIN_PER_RANK  + 1) + MIN_PER_RANK);
        animateValue(randomvalue, 0);
    }
}, 60000); //1 minute

function processdata(top, param) { 
    if (start){
        console.log(param.toString())
    }
}
```

The code is running in this way:
The node chooses a random number as a counter, starts to auto-decrement the counter. When node reaches to zero, it processes the data for 1 minute. Then, the node will sleep for another 1 minute. After that, the node will wake up and start the process again.
How to make the node starts a counter right away after 1 minute of process instead of getting to sleep?
How I could solve it?
Thanks in adavance

the output:

```
MQTT connected  true
4
3
2
1
0
finish counter
process data for 1 minute
{"sensorvalue":"91","timestamp":1611236199874,"topicsensor":"sensor1","dataID":"0a9e9f87-51b4-4a37-91d5-773de6869491"}
{"sensorvalue":"99","timestamp":1611236214889,"topicsensor":"sensor1","dataID":"109bbf17-78b8-4357-90ac-ca23f760a4eb"}

start counter
3
2
1
0
finish counter
process data for 1 minute
{"sensorvalue":"80","timestamp":1611236219894,"topicsensor":"sensor1","dataID":"71398516-3757-4a0b-ad61-20e9a17891cc"}
{"sensorvalue":"80","timestamp":1611236219894,"topicsensor":"sensor1","dataID":"71398516-3757-4a0b-ad61-20e9a17891cc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be that what do you want.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://localhost';
var client = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL);

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("MQTT connected  " + client.connected);
  client.subscribe('DAG1');
})

var MIN_PER_RANK = 3;
var MAX_PER_RANK = 5;

function animateValue(start, end) {
  if (start === end) return;
  var current = start;
  var increment = end > start ? 1 : -1;

  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    current += increment;
    console.log(current);
    if (current == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

    if (current === 0) {
      console.log("finish counter")
      console.log("process data for 1 minute")
      client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        processdata(topic, message)
      })
    }

  }, 1000);
}

function processdata(top, param) {
  console.log(param.toString())
  // ... do what do you want
  animateValue(randomValue(), 0); // After all code inside processData() restart the function animateValue()
}

function randomValue() { // Generate a random number
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_PER_RANK - MIN_PER_RANK + 1) + MIN_PER_RANK);
}

animateValue(randomValue(), 0); // All start from here
```

I used the callback and recursive function.

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately, It is not working as I really want. It just keeps auto-decrement the counter and processes in the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, you want that after the `processdata` restart the countdown? I tried to correct the code in the above comment, I removed the `setInterval`, moving the callback inside the `processdata` and create a function for get a random number.
Now the script starts imediatly and at the end of `processdata` restart the countdown.